# Need a function to import extremly messy txt files

Tags: r, function, file, import

I´m a complete newbie and I need to find a way to import really messy txt files. This means there are a lot of weird different seperators and/or weird of no end of line seperators. I tried my best by using read.delim and specifing the arguments but nothing really seemed to work... There are various different files with different seperators and end of line seperators. I would like to find something that does the job for all of the files. I thought about defining a function myself but I can´t seem to find a good way to approach it...

[example of a specifically hard to import txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVaHg.png)

Comment: i suggest uploading an actual .txt file else no-one can recreate your problem

Answer (score 0):

You could try `data.table::fread` function because it very often just gets things done without the need to specify many parameters. It will certainly not work for ALL messy files though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. It should work for most txt files.
Just read the function and then call `readfile("Path/to/your/file", "your_end_of_line_sep", "your_sep")`. If one of the sep is an escape character make sure u put '/' in front of it

```r
readfile <- function(file, eol_str, sep_str = ";") {
  row_list <- sapply(scan(file, what = character(), sep = eol_str), 
                     strsplit, split = sep_str)
  df <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, row_list[2:length(row_list)]))
  row.names(df) <- NULL
  names(df) <- row_list[[1]]
  return(df)
}
```